# ReplaceAll method is not working correctly - replace regex with regex pattern

Tags: java

I saw plenty of questions regarding problem with `replaceAll` but it didn't work for me.
I would like to replace occurance of particular pattern with pattern itself (so later on I will be able to run sql and find similiar records based on regex value)
by given:

> https://internal-gateway.com/users/4e8a4741-dd89-4cdd-a7c3-3b2f7044e142

it shoud return

> https://internal-gateway.com/users/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89AB][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}

my code:

```
private final static String UUID_PATTERN = "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89AB][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}";
private final static String SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN = "894803[0-9]{13}";
private final static String MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN = "[0-9]{9}";
private final static String MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN = "[0-9]{11}";
private Optional<WebApp> checkRegexes(String url, Long id) {
    String urlToLookFor = url.replaceAll(UUID_PATTERN,UUID_PATTERN);
    urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN,SIM_NUMBER_PATTERN);
    urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN,MSISDN_LONG_PATTERN);
    urlToLookFor=urlToLookFor.replaceAll(MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN,MSISDN_SHORT_PATTERN);

    return waRepository.getWebAppByRegex(urlToLookFor,id);
}
```

however in given example value replaceall is not replacing anything, can anyone give me a hint what is my mistake?

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match your value

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match the value : [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3RtKw1/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.replaceAll()` is case-sensitive, and your pattern doesn't match your string here:

`[89AB][0-9a-f]{3}`: "AB" is upper case

`a7c3`: "a" is lower case

Just replace `[89AB]` with `[89ab]`, or use a case-insensitive pattern matching method.

Comment: Didn't noticed that my regex testing plugin has disabled case sensitive ;/ thanks for pointing this out, it looks like adding (?i) before pattern in replaceAll worked !